# Sample code to plan a trip using OpenTripPlanner as a jar dependency

Tags: java, routing, network, road, opentripplanner

I would like to use OpenTripPlanner as a jar dependency in my project and do some routing with it. I have followed the steps at https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/src/test/java/org/opentripplanner/GtfsTest.java and they do seem to work if the start and end points of a `RoutingRequest` are near a transit stop but don't work otherwise. 
 The following line returns me an empty list:

```
List<GraphPath> paths = new GraphPathFinder(router).getPaths(routingRequest);
```

I think its because the road network is missing from the graph. Specifically, the code in https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/src/test/java/org/opentripplanner/GtfsTest.java only adds a transit network to the graph (the `GtfsBundle`). The road network is never added to the graph. So my question is could anyone please show me how to add the road network to the graph? I have the road network as an OSM PBF file. I seek a complete end-to-end example.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentripplanner-users/AKCnGaGZE6k) link is saying at one point:

> once the data have been loaded the geometries of the  streets are
>   extra information purely for presentation purposes.

Is the OSM road network not used for routing?

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because you have only told us what you want to do and alluded to some things that you have tried. I think you should include a code snippet that illustrates precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @PolyGeo regarding the code snippet, I followed the exact steps at https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/src/test/java/org/opentripplanner/GtfsTest.java. You can see that code is pretty long so not pasting it in the question. I have highlighted the line where I am stuck.

Comment: Long code should not be posted in a question here.  That is why we ask you to develop from your code a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that illustrates precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.  There may be potential answerers here who will vote to re-open your question and be happy to follow links to find code to debug but I am not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I found [this](https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/blob/master/src/test/java/org/opentripplanner/graph_builder/module/osm/TestOpenStreetMapGraphBuilder.java) code to load road network.

```
Graph gg = new Graph();

        OpenStreetMapModule loader = new OpenStreetMapModule();
        loader.setDefaultWayPropertySetSource(new DefaultWayPropertySetSource());
        FileBasedOpenStreetMapProviderImpl provider = new FileBasedOpenStreetMapProviderImpl(); // this works with XML. For PBF use BinaryFileBasedOpenStreetMapProviderImpl

        File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getResource("map.osm.gz").getFile(), "UTF-8"));

        provider.setPath(file);
        loader.setProvider(provider);

        loader.buildGraph(gg, extra);
```

But even better was to do following:

> put 1_gtfs.zip and seattle_washington.osm.pbf under c:\Users\user\otp
>   and then run
>
> java -Xmx2G -jar target/otp-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build
>   "c:\Users\user\otp" --basePath "c:\Users\user\otp" --verbose

It should generate `Graph.obj` in same directory. Now you can use following code to do the routing:

```
Graph graph = Graph.load(file, LoadLevel.DEBUG);
        Router router = new Router("TEST", graph);
        Leg[] legs = planTrip(home, work, graph, true, 1, router);
```

where the code for `planTrip` is below

```
public static Leg[] planTrip(Location start, Location end, Graph graph,
                                boolean preferLeastTransfers,
                                int legCount,
                                Router router)
    {
        long dateTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000l - 24*60*60;
        RoutingRequest routingRequest = new RoutingRequest();
        routingRequest.setNumItineraries(1);
        routingRequest.setArriveBy(dateTime < 0);
        routingRequest.dateTime = Math.abs(dateTime);
        routingRequest.from = new GenericLocation(start.latitude, start.longitude);
        routingRequest.to = new GenericLocation(end.latitude, end.longitude);
        routingRequest.setRoutingContext(graph);
        routingRequest.setWheelchairAccessible(false);
        routingRequest.transferPenalty = (preferLeastTransfers ? 300 : 0);
        routingRequest.setModes(new TraverseModeSet(TraverseMode.WALK, TraverseMode.BUS));        
        routingRequest.setOtherThanPreferredRoutesPenalty(0);
        // The walk board cost is set low because it interferes with test 2c1.
        // As long as boarding has a very low cost, waiting should not be "better" than riding
        // since this makes interlining _worse_ than alighting and re-boarding the same line.
        // TODO rethink whether it makes sense to weight waiting to board _less_ than 1.
        routingRequest.setWaitReluctance(1);
        routingRequest.setWalkBoardCost(30);

        List<GraphPath> paths = new GraphPathFinder(router).getPaths(routingRequest);
        TripPlan tripPlan = GraphPathToTripPlanConverter.generatePlan(paths, routingRequest);
        // Stored in instance field for use in individual tests
        Itinerary itinerary = tripPlan.itinerary.get(0);

        assert itinerary.legs.size() > 0;

        return itinerary.legs.toArray(new Leg[legCount]);
    }
```